# Maximal subalgebras of simple Lie algebras.

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

Does anyone know how I can access Dynkin's papers on the classification of maximal subalgebras of simple finite dimensional complex Lie algebras? V.V. Morozov also worked on this topic, how can I access his results or any other results on this topic?

Comment: You can access them following this [MO link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60315/modern-reference-for-maximal-connected-subgroups-of-compact-lie-groups), i.e., there are two important (and long) papers by Dynkin in 1952, published by AMS in Series 2, Volume 6 of their translation series (1957), pages 111-378: Semisimple subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras and Maximal subgroups of the classical groups.